# work done by a vector field from a potential function

Tags: vector-fields, line-integrals

I'm trying to find the work done using a scalar potential however the work done from a potential function never matches a line integral. do I not understand something, why cant I get this right?

$$
F = (\sin(x), 0, 2z) \\
r = (\rho, \rho, \rho^2) \hspace{1cm} 0 \leq \rho \leq \pi
$$
Find the work by constructing a scalar potential.

These are my attempts:

> [image: atempts at question]

Comment: Clearly a potential could be $\phi(x,y,z) = -\cos(x) + z^2,\  \nabla \phi = F$.

Comment: what am i doing wrong, i thought i was following the correct method.

why dont i get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second attempt was (aside from some notational mistakes) fine until the very end, when you computed $f(0,0,2\pi)$ instead of $f(\pi,\pi,\pi^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the integral without the potential, note that
$$
-\cos(\pi) - \cos(0) = 0.
$$
So, your answer should be $\pi^4$.  Then, using the potential $f(x,y,z) := -\cos(x) + z^2$, you have
$$
f(\pi, \pi, \pi^2) - f(0,0,0) = \pi^4.
$$